# Cordova Plugin to ask for Ratings

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, rating

I am looking for a cordova plugin that asks for ratings similar to askingpoint.com. Basically I need a plugin that can send a popup to the user to rate the app after a specific task or amount of days using the app. Of course this needs to be for Phonegap/Cordova

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check these link out...

https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate (this one is easy to set up)

http://www.joshuawinn.com/adding-rate-button-to-cordova-based-mobile-app-android-ios-etc/ (haven't used this but heard good reviews abt it)

Hope it helps.!